# Why notebook throw error "no module named tensorflow"?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I installed tensorflow in my virtual environment using virtualenv.I have installed python 3.7. and I ensure that tensorflow is installed in my virtual environment(I already checked using pip freeze command).This is also one evidence that ensures tensorflow is installed.
[image]

But when I started notebook in virtual environment and try to import it as below

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It throws message

```
No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I am using only Python not other packages like anaconda and miniconda.

Comment: Try making sure Tensorflow is actually installed on venv by running 'pip freeze'. Also make sure that the kernel is living in the same venv. Anyhow, I would highly encourage you to use Google Colabratory as your development env. It will just solve most of the configuration problems for you.

Comment: How to make sure kernel is located on same directory as tensorflow virtualenv.